# MySQL Join, Select, multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am really stuck at this this multiple condition queries.

There are 2 sets of sample data:

[image: Data]

Here's What I want:

[image: Want]

I want to know the students that been honorable mentioned by times, ie n=1, n=2, n=3 ... What is their average amount received in 2012 per price, per month, per different type of rewards, and return NULL if there's no value in a particular Month.

So far I have

```
SELECT Type_Of_Reward, Honorable_Mention, MONTH(date)       
FROM Data_2 LEFT JOIN      
SELECT(Honorable_Mention, COUNT(*) FROM Data_2 GROUP BY Honorable_Mention ON Student_ID = Honorable_Mention)        
WHERE YEAR(Data_1.date)=2012 AND...
```

Any comments/helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Databases cannot produce data out of nothing. If you want "empty" months represented, then you'll have to provide a list of the date types you want, e.g. a temporary table that contains the years/months you want, that you can join against. Plus, converting the individual months into columns like that calls for a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. There's workarounds, but they make the query VERY ugly and VERY difficult to maintain.

Comment: @MarcB it is possible to achieve that with DATEFORMAT and GROUP BY. The question is are we talking about generating data for only this year ever? So it is a 'run once and throw away' query?

Comment: @Marc B, Thanks for your input. Since I am fairly new to MySQL and I know that it would been a lot easier to do such a thing in R/Pivot Table. However, I was asked to do it in MySQL. :(

Comment: Please read up on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns).  You will need to take this concept, and use the MONTH() function within the CASE statement, making a new column for every month

Comment: @AgRizzo Thank you, the link helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one by using join and using case for all months *make sure you have set proper datatype for date column* if you are using any server side language i recommend you to make this type of data representation by using  server side language for now you can try this

```
SELECT d.Type_Of_Reward, d2.Honorable_Mention,
(CASE WHEN d2.`Honorable_Mention` IS NOT NULL AND MONTH(d.`date`)=1 THEN  d2.`Honorable_Mention`   ELSE 0  END) AS jan,
. //for other months
.
.
.

(CASE WHEN d2.`Honorable_Mention_id` IS NOT NULL AND MONTH(d.`date`)=10 THEN  d2.`Honorable_Mention`   ELSE 0  END) AS `oct`
FROM 
`data_1` d LEFT JOIN `data_2` d2 ON(d.`id`=d2 .`Honorable_Mention`)
```

### [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: Thank you @dianuj your structure is really helpful. I just have to figure out how to put the average price in somewhere.

Comment: `CASE WHEN` rocks! :) (Even with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`)